# In SceneKit, shader modifier. How do I use the texcoord second channel in the GeometryEntry?

Tags: ios, objective-c, shader, scenekit, metal

I am using SceneKit shader modifier with Metal in iOS, Xcode.
Specifically, the GeometryEntry of the shader modifier, specify that you can read input from:

```
struct SCNShaderGeometry {
  vec3 position;
  vec3 normal;
  vec4 tangent;
  vec2 texcoords[kSCNTexcoordCount];
} _geometry;
```

Specifically, I cannot set values to _geometry.texcoords[1] while I can set and read from _geometry.texcoords[0]

There doesn't seem to be any semantic to differentiate between the two, and using the same semantics twice, does nothing that I can tell.

Here is the way I tried to build the vertex buffer Semantics:

```
SCNGeometrySource *vertexSource, *tcoordSource, *vertexSource2, *timeSource, *rgbSource, *normalSource;
 
vertexSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:data
                                                semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex
                                             vectorCount:verticesAmount
                                         floatComponents:YES
                                     componentsPerVector:3 // x, y, z
                                       bytesPerComponent:sizeof(float)
                                              dataOffset:0
                                              dataStride:sizeof(VertexConfeti)];
 
tcoordSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:data
                                                semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord
                                             vectorCount:verticesAmount
                                         floatComponents:YES
                                     componentsPerVector:2 // s, t
                                       bytesPerComponent:sizeof(float)
                                              dataOffset:sizeof(float)*3
                                              dataStride:sizeof(VertexConfeti)];
    
timeSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:data
                                                semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord
                                             vectorCount:verticesAmount
                                         floatComponents:YES
                                     componentsPerVector:2 // t, a
                                       bytesPerComponent:sizeof(float)
                                              dataOffset:sizeof(float)*6
                                              dataStride:sizeof(VertexConfeti)];


vertexSource2 = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:data
                                                semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticNormal
                                             vectorCount:verticesAmount
                                         floatComponents:YES
                                     componentsPerVector:3 // cx, cy, cz
                                       bytesPerComponent:sizeof(float)
                                              dataOffset:sizeof(float)*8
                                              dataStride:sizeof(VertexConfeti)];

rgbSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:data
                                                semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticColor
                                             vectorCount:verticesAmount
                                         floatComponents:YES
                                     componentsPerVector:3 // rgb
                                       bytesPerComponent:sizeof(float)
                                              dataOffset:sizeof(float)*11
                                              dataStride:sizeof(VertexConfeti)];
normalSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithData:data
                                                semantic:SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTangent
                                             vectorCount:verticesAmount
                                         floatComponents:YES
                                     componentsPerVector:3 // rgb
                                       bytesPerComponent:sizeof(float)
                                              dataOffset:sizeof(float)*14
                                              dataStride:sizeof(VertexConfeti)];

SCNGeometry * geometry = [SCNGeometry geometryWithSources:@[vertexSource, tcoordSource, timeSource, vertexSource2, rgbSource, normalSource] elements:@[element]];
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Recompute your data offsets. You seemed to have the same order as in structure.

Comment: It has no effect, I was just trying to do it 3 float aligned, because I thought maybe that would be an issue

Answer (score 0):

What I have deduced from your code :

```
struct VertexConfeti {
    vertex : vec3  // SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex
    tcoord : vec2 // SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord
    // offset of time should be 5*float which may the flooding ones wrong or have you a float before ?
    time : vec2 // SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord at offset 6*float <- wrong : should be 5*f
    vertex2 : vec3 // SCNGeometrySourceSemanticNormal at offset 8*f
    rgb : vec3 (( SCNGeometrySourceSemanticColor at offset 11*f
    normal : vec3 // SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTangent at offset 14*f
}
```

This is quite different from SCNShaderGeometry.

For the 2 textcoord : You may try to use 1 source with 4 components per vector (aka s,t+t,a)